# Text box validation in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a form with a text box that should only accept 4 digit year values between 1980-2011. 
I'm sure there should be a simple c# validation control to implement this validation check, but I can't seem to find it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Windows Forms doesn't have validation controls

Comment: What is wrong with checkin it on keypress? UC that you'd find would do the same thing anyway..

Comment: So what would be the best way to implement checks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch Validating event and add you validation code in there.

For a complete example check MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx).

For simple validation you can also use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

First I'd say, use the max length property set to 4 so that no extra characters can be entered

Beyond that you would have to hook up your own controls to validate it (could be a on text changed validation, on lost focus, etc) that would check that only digits are entered and they are between your specified values

Answer (score 1):

A [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) would do the trick. Set the mask to your needs: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
But I doubt it will check if the value is between a range. It probably only checks if the value is a integer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not going to write all the code here but here's what I'd do:

In textchanged event of your textbox;

- Check if entered value is numeric
- Check if it meets the pattern (compare chars with what you want)

For this one, you need to compare each number one by one. I'd suggest you to write a method which parses the text and compares them with your expected values. Something like this:

```
private bool IsNumberValid(string text)
{
    String min = "1980",max=2011;
    try
    {
        int minNumber = Convert.ToInt32(min.Substring(0,text.length));
        int maxNumber = Convert.ToInt32(max.Substring(0,text.length));
        int myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(text);
        if(myNumber <= max && myNumber >= min)
            return true;
     }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false; // number is not numeric
    }
    return false;
 }
```

There may be small errors, didn't write it in VS. You'd need to check the length of the text and not call this method if it is 0.

Comment: I don't get this code, why is the Min and Max specified as a string at all and not a int, why are they declared in the method meaning they'll be recreated and re parsed every time you check it's valid, this seems like a strange approach